# Passar parâmetro (um objeto da lista) de View (tipo Lista) para Controller. Asp.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, html5

Possuo uma View do tipo `"List<SimpleUser>"` e quero passar por parâmetro para o meu controller o objeto que esta no meu foreach, porém esta chegando nulo sendo feito da seguinte forma:

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
}

<!-- search form -->
<form action="#" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar entre seus clientes/pacientes..." />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type='submit' name='seach' id='search-btn' class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>            
        </span>
    </div>
</form>

@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
    foreach (var sUser in Model)
    {
        <div>            
            @Html.ActionLink(@sUser.Name, "ClientDetails", "ProfessionalUserHasClient", new { simpleUser = sUser })
        </div>
    }
}
else
{
    <label>Você não tem clientes/pacientes vinculados.</label>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ClientDetails(SimpleUser simpleUser)
{
    SimpleUser sUser = ViewBag.SimpleUser as SimpleUser;
    return View();
}
```

Se modificar para `@Html.Action()`, ele passa perfeitamente porém é carregada dentro da `View`, uma parte do layout inteiro, na qual obviamente não deve ser carregado, segue um print de como ficaria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não passe pelo `ActionLink` o objeto inteiro. Passe apenas o Id do objeto. Fazer o *binding* de um objeto inteiro é muito trabalhoso e tem uma boa chance de não funcionar.

Troque:

```
@Html.ActionLink(@sUser.Name, "ClientDetails", "ProfessionalUserHasClient", new { simpleUser = sUser })
```

Por:

```
@Html.ActionLink(@sUser.Name, "ClientDetails", "ProfessionalUserHasClient", new { id = sUser.Id }, null)
```

Não esqueça do `null` no final, senão vai cair no `overload` errado do `ActionLink`.

Você vai ter que carregar os dados de novo. Não vai ter jeito.

A `Action` fica assim:

```
public ActionResult ClientDetails(int id)
{
    var sUser = context.SimpleUsers.SingleOrDefault(su => su.Id == id);
    return View(sUser);
}
```

Não entendi a parte que você carrega os dados e não os envia pra *View*. Imagino que `Model` da próxima `View` seja carregado com as instruções da `Action`. Portanto:

```
return View(sUser);
```

Envia os dados carregados para a `View`.

Answer (score 3):

Explicação:

Em um [`@Html.ActionLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) é retornado um elemento `a` que no caso seria `<a href=""></a>`, por isso tal instrução não funciona, retornar um dado complexo nesse caso não vai surtir efeito, enquando em um [`@Html.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721266%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) é retornado um saída em `HTML`, e executado no caso um Controller e Action, inclusive com dados do tipo complexos (`class, object`) ou tipos primitivos, tendo uma renderização como dito de um `HTML`, como no seu questionamento tem tal execucação.

Então, são coisas diferentes tendo outros resultados. Por padrão quando se utiliza [`@Html.ActionLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) é passado no seu `a`, uma identificação do registro (o Id por exemplo, que identifique tal linha), exemplo:

**1) @Html.ActionLink**

*Na View:*

```cs
@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
    foreach (var sUser in Model)
    {
        <div>            
            @Html.ActionLink(@sUser.Name, "ClientDetails", "ProfessionalUserHasClient", new { Id = sUser.Id }, null)
        </div>
    }
}
```

*Na Action:*

```cs
public ActionResult ClientDetails(int? Id)
{
    //recupera o Id
    return View();
}
```

---

**2) @Html.Action**

É utilizado para carregar no caso PartialView e de grande utilidade para tal, ou seja, fragmentos de páginas carregadas em layout já existente, com funcionalidades por exemplo, de cacheamento para aumentar a performance, diminuindo o trafego na rede.

*Na View*

```cs
@Html.Action("Menu", "Home")
```

*Na Action*

```cs
public PartialViewResult Menu()
{
    return PartialView("Menu");
}
```

Comment: Usando o ActionLink o Id esta passando como null. Porém como A partial View eu não consegui fazer funcionar. Tem como explicar mais o código da partial? Se funcionar já esta ótimo sem aparecer metade do layout de novo hehe

Comment: Eu preciso que seja um link, para essa ClientDetails.

Comment: @LuizNegrini eu fiz pra você como deveria ser coloquei no ActionLink um `new {Id = sUser.Id}` e coloquei na Action `ClientDetails(int? Id)`, já foi passado isso para que você adeque ao seu item e funcione igual um link como você mesmo já tinha relatado!

Comment: o seu código não funcionou pois faltou um parametro nele.

Comment: @LuizNegrini você ta muito enganado, olha lá no código e praticamente é igual a resposta que você deu como correta!!! Acredite ou não a resposta é igualzinha! mas, tudo bem!

Comment: falta o parametro null após o routevalues